# AngularJS playPause function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is our javascript:

```
function playPause(audio){
    var sound=document.getElementById(audio);
    if (sound.paused){
        sound.play();
    } else {
        sound.pause();
        sound.currentTime=0;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create an AngularJS Controller with the same function. How should I do this?

Comment: That's the same! You can use `angular.element(<El>)`

Comment: Can you provide you html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.playPause = function(audio){
        var sound = document.getElementById(audio);
        if (sound.paused){
            sound.play();
        } else {
            sound.pause();
            sound.currentTime=0;
        }
    }
})

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <player id="somePlayer"></player>
        <button ng-click="playPause('somePlayer')">Play or Pause</a>
    </div>
</div>
```